# Lazily populating Android ViewFlipper children

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a ViewFlipper in which I display a large number of images, loaded from the sqlite database. If I initialise each ViewFlipper child on startup, there's an unreasonable delay whilst all the images are loaded from the db. Instead I want to populate the views one at a time, 'lazily', just before the user transitions from one child to the next. I need to populate the next view *before* setDisplayedChild(next) is called as I have animations applied to the transition. However ViewFlipper doesn't seem to have a getChildAt(int i) method which would enable me to do this - you only seem to be able to getDisplayedChild(). Any ideas how I might achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by keeping a list of views outside the view flipper - doh